# multiple records returned on the same date sort by phone number in ascending order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am coding an angular app, that tracks tuxedo rentals.The app contains a table that is populated by an array that I have in the controller.

The first direction I have is to list the items in the table by return date in ascending order.  I did this by using the lodash orderBy filter.

The second direction is where I am stuck:
if there are multiple records returned on the same date sort by phone number in ascending order.
I know I can sort the phone numbers, I need help figuring out how I can sort only the ones with the same date(not the entire collection), without altering the order of the return dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this much more easily using Angular's sort directive. You can specify multiple sort-by columns, which it does in order.

The syntax is `{{ array | orderBy : expression : reverse }}` , where you can put an array of order sequence like `['dateReturned', 'phoneNumber']` for the `expression` argument, and you can also put `true` or `false` (or leave it blank) for the `reverse` argument if you'd like to toggle ASC/DESC

It would look something like this, without a reverse argument:

```html
<tr class="dataRow" ng-repeat="r in vm.rentalRecords track by $index | orderBy:['dateReturned','phoneNumber']">
```